# Load UK Latitude/Longitude into custom Google Map on initialize

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am creating a custom google map that I want to add to a web page.  The following line determines which part of the map displays when the initialize() {} is executed:

```
 center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.736129,-1.988229)
```

The above line just displays a portion of the South East UK.

What I can't seem to figure out (or find anywhere) is the LatLng for displaying JUST the whole of the UK in a div with width: 700px x height: 900px ?

I have tried zoom level of 6 but this does not give me the following portion of the map on load:

[image]

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You have to change the zoom level. Latitude and longitude just define the center of the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply a zoom level around 6 and you should see the whole UK:

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.736129,-1.988229),
zoom: 6
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have updated my question to show a portion of the map I am trying to display.  Zoom level 6 is very close but not specific enough.

Comment: Then adjust the  zoom level until you get your desired area (bigger values means closer zoom)